# Strong monoidal equivalence from a symmetric monoidal category to a strict monoidal category

Tags: proof-writing, category-theory, monoidal-categories, diagram-chasing

This question is related to point $(1)$ in this answer:

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190402/229776

Let $(\mathsf{C}, \otimes, 1, \alpha, l ,r, s)$ be a symmetric monoidal category, $(\mathsf{C}_s, \otimes_s, 1_s)$ a strict monoidal category and $F\colon\mathsf{C}\to\mathsf{C}_s$ a (strong) monoidal equivalence together with $(J_{X,Y}\colon F(X)\otimes_s F(Y)\to F(X\otimes Y))_{X,Y \in \mathsf{C}}$

The aforementioned answer claims that $\mathsf{C}_s$ is also a symmetric monoidal category by symmetry induced by $s$. For each $A \in \mathsf{C}_s$, choose $X_A \in \mathsf{C}$ and an isomorphism $f_A\colon F(X_A)\to A$. It seems a canonical choice for a symmetry isomorphism in $\mathsf{C}_s$ is $(f_B\otimes_s f_A)\circ J^{-1}_{X_B,X_A}\circ F(s_{X_A,X_B})\circ J_{X_A,X_B} \circ (f^{-1}_A\otimes_s f^{-1}_B)$, which we denote by $t_{A,B}$. It's not hard to prove that $t$ is natural and one of the axioms for symmetry isomorphism (relating unit and symmetry) is straightforward due to $\mathsf{C}_s$ being strict. However, proving that the diagram

[image]

commutes feels beyond me.

Of course, by symmetry in $\mathsf{C}$ and functoriality, the diagram

[image]

commutes, so one needs to use this.

My idea is to use the commutative hexagon in the middle and to build commutative squares around its edges using paths of the form: $$J_{X_A\otimes X_B,X_C}\circ (J_{X_A,X_B}\otimes 1_{F(X_C)})\circ((f^{-1}_A\otimes f^{-1}_B)\otimes f^{-1}_C)\colon (A\otimes B)\otimes C\to F((X_A\otimes X_B)\otimes X_C).$$ It feels like I'm in the right direction, but I still can't make it work. If I have a say, I would like an answer to help me with the details, since it's what I'm having a trouble with.

Comment: You should take the diagram you want to prove commutes, write the same diagram by replacing $A,B,C$ with $F(X_A),F(X_B),F(X_C)$, draw the appropriate maps between the two, and prove that the one with $A,B,C$ commutes iff the one with $F(X_A),F(X_B),F(X_C)$ does. Then for this second one, by monoidality of $F$, you get a map of diagrams from your diagram to $F$ of the first diagram written with $X_A,X_B,X_C$, and since this map is an isomorphism, it suffices to show that the latter commutes. Finally, the latter commutes because it is $F$ of a commutative diagram

Comment: @Max Yeah, it felt to me like this is the way. However, when I try to proceed formally, I get stuck in details.

Comment: I can't do it right now but I'll try to write a more precise answer later

Comment: @Max Thanks, I look forward to it!

Comment: @Max Any luck? I've tried to follow your suggestion, but failed. One of the problems I've encountered that $F(X_{A\otimes B})$ is not necessarily equal to $F(X_A)\otimes F(X_B)$ and the same for $f_{A\otimes B}$ and $f_A\otimes f_B$. Perhaps, the construction of the symmetry isomorphism for $\mathsf{C}_s$ is wrong?

Comment: They're not equal but you have a transformation from the latter to the former which commutes with everything appropriately. I haven't had the time to write it down properly (a bit busy) but I wrote a sketch of it and I'm sure there's no problem

Comment: @Max I see. I'll wait for your answer and meanwhile will try to do it myself. Take as much time as you need, but, please, don't forget about me. :) Thanks a lot for your attention! :)

Comment: @Max It appears I've got it. Thank you for your assistance. Your initial suggestion was spot on!

Comment: Well I was planning on writing it today, I'm glad you worked it out - it'll save me some big diagrams to write down. Do tell me if you need more help !